# How Does This Reaction Proceed?

Tags: organic-chemistry

$$
\ce{CH3OH + CH3CCNa+ ->  ?}
$$

The answer is $\ce{CH3CCH +CH3ONa+}$ but I don't understand why.

Comment: @R.M. http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/3052

Answer (score 2):

$\ce{CH_{3}C#CNa}$ exists in a solution as a cation and anion shown below: 
$\ce{CH_{3}C#CNa  <=> CH_{3}C#C- + Na+} $

$\ce{CH_{3}OH}$ has very slightly acidic hydrogen (thanks to electron pulling ability of oxygen), that can be removed by a strong base.

When put in the same solution, $\ce{CH_{3}C#C-}$ will pull out $\ce{H+}$ from $\ce{CH_{3}OH}$ like so:
$\ce{CH_{3}C#C- + CH_{3}OH  <=> CH_{3}C#CH + CH_{3}O-}$

$\ce{CH_{3}C#CH}$ is a weaker acid than $\ce{CH_{3}OH}$, which means that $\ce{CH_{3}C#C-}$ is a stronger base than $\ce{CH_{3}O-}$. Therefore, $\ce{CH_{3}C#C-}$ will completely pull out hydrogen from methanol.

And overall reaction looks like the following:

$\ce{CH_{3}C#CNa + CH_{3}OH  <=> CH_{3}C#CH + CH_{3}ONa}$

Comment: Propyne is much weaker acid so reaction will be complete

Comment: @Mithoron You're right. pKa of propyne is much bigger than pKa of methanol. I updated the answer.